# Problem with futures in c++0x 

Tags: c++11, future

I have written a small program , to understand how futures work in c++0x. while running the code I get an error like " error: 'printEn' was not declared in this scope". I am unable to understand what the problem is..Kindly point out what I am doing wrong here and if possible write the correct code for the same..

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int printFn()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
    {

        cout << "thread " <<  i << endl;
    }

    return 1;
}



int main()
{

    future<int> the_answer2=async(printEn);
    future<int> the_answer1=async(printEn);


   return 0;
}
```

Edit :

After making the change to printFn while running the program i get an error message " version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by ./a.out)". what does this indicate ?

Comment: In regards to the GLIBCXX comment, a common idiom for versioning is to introduce some new symbol such as "GLIBCXX_3.4.14" into each new shared library version. Generally these version symbols are preseved until some sort of backwards compatibility is lost. The idea is that users of the library can then have a corresponding unresolved symbol that is wired up at link time. This way the users of the library need not ship the library, but merely rely on being linked to some other (possibly newer) library as long as it has this symbol. The C++ runtime is the most common place I've seen this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong function name `printEn` <-> `printFn`.

Comment: Your welcome! `was not declared in this scope` means check namespace, include, name of the function/variable

Comment: Now while running it I get an error msg " version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by ./a.out)" This compiled fine though!!

Comment: @Eternal: That isn't directly related to your original question, which seems to be solved. Why not ask a new one about that specific problem?